# Does APK API level override JAR API level

Tags: java, android, api, sdk

I have an Android APK file built using API 19. This APK includes JAR that was built using API 16. When I run this APK on the device, I noticed that API calls included in the JAR are behaving as they would in API level 19. The specific API is AlarmManager's set method. This method behaves differently between API 16 and API 19.

Based on this observation, I am getting the impression that at run time, the API level decided by system is based upon the APK's API level. The API level of JAR included in the APK gets overridden by APK's API level. Is this correct?

Here is what I found in Android documentation of AlarmManager's set API:

*Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later. 
Applications whose targetSdkVersion is before API 19 will continue to get the previous alarm behavior: all of their scheduled alarms will be treated as exact.*

It is not clear to me if the targetSdkVersion of APK will override the targetSdkVersion of JAR embedded in the APK.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's based off of the version the device is running. If the device is running version 19 it will use that version of the API. If you need to handle specific versions differently, you need to check that using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Comment: @VERT9x is right, Android comes on your phone with its SDK. Whatever the API of your libraries or your application itself, the device SDK is the one executing the code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the question will additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution for this issue. The target SDK version in the APK file overrides the target SDK version in the included JARS.

Specifically, in the above situation, when I changed the targetSdkVersion of the APK to 16, the AlarmManager's set API started behaving as it was in API 16. When I changed the targetSdkVersion of the APK to 19, the AlarmManager's set API behaving as it was in API 19.